# No such property: i for class, for-loop

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to create a list of years, starting from 2019, for example, let's assume that we are in 2020 already - in that case, a list should consist of `[2019, 2020, 2021]` years. If we are in 2021, it should be `[2019, 2020, 2021, 2022]`...

I'm trying to loop through the years and add them into a created list:

```
def years = []
def startYear = 2019
def currentYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date());
def nextYear = currentYear.toInteger() + 1;

for (i = startYear; i <= nextYear; i++) {
    years.add(i.toString());
}
```

But I'm receiving the following error: `No such property: i for class....`
Am I doing something wrong in the for-loop? 
I'm trying to use this example from [Grails Cookbook](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following, you forgot to declare the variable in for loop, which led to the error. The lessons from grails.asia are conceptual so they have removed some key details where they assume you know how to fix the code to run it. Not great for beginners though.

```
def years = []
def startYear = 2019
def currentYear = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date());
def nextYear = currentYear.toInteger() + 1;

for (int i = startYear; i <= nextYear; i++) {
    years.add(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I know, I'm not answering the question.

But i'd like to show a shorter code for this task.

one liner:

```
def years = (2019..new Date().toYear().value+1).toList()
```

`(x..y)` in groovy results [Range](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Range.html) from `x` to `y` that implements List interface

`range.toList()` converts it to ArrayList